# Realtime equalizer?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack, realtime, equalizer

What realtime equalizers are there that work with JACK? I have heard of Calf Studio Gear, but not sure if it will work or how good it is.

Ones that won't work are: pulseaudio-equalizer, jackeq, jamin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calf plugins; jack-rack and non-mixer will host LADSPA effects for sound processing in JACK

for studio effects including some equalisers, install package swh-plugins in addition to host package.